# How to apply a mathematical function to a list of objects in R?

Tags: r, list, function

So I have a large list of objects (200+) which only contain a numeric value. I want to apply the same mathematical (get the 80% of the value) function for all of them, but it's not working out for me.

Here's a small example.

```
a = 680

b = 820

c = 1040

list = as.list(ls())

fun = function(x){x*.8}

for (i in list){
  fun(i)
}
```

And I get an error saying `non-numeric argument to binary operator`. I get that this might be happening because the software is applying the function to the names in the list and no the numerical values, but for the life of me I can't make it work and haven't been able to find this exact issue online. I know the answer must be so simple but I'm a newbie, really. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!!

Comment: change your list to `list = mget(ls())` instead of `as.list` use `mget` then you can be able to do all the other operations

Comment: This is it. I appreciate Jason's and vectorson's answers, but having 200+ elements in my environment I don't want the create the vector by hand. I didn't know the "mget" function. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the `mget` function: This is a multivariate format of `get`

thus:

```
a = 680

b = 820

c = 1040

list = mget(ls())## This is the part you need to change

fun = function(x){x*.8}

for (i in list){
  fun(i)
}
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you Onyambu. Can't upvote yet (too new), but this was the solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use `eapply` to apply a function to all variables in an environment. However, I recommend you to first build a list of numeric variables and use `lapply(myList, fun)` as variables in an environment can easily be manipulated unintentionally. Refer to the code below:

```
##### Solution 1 using eapply() #####
# Build a new temporary environment to save all numeric variables
tempEnv <- new.env()
tempEnv$a = 680
tempEnv$b = 820
tempEnv$c = 1040

fun = function(x){x*.8}

# apply fun() to all variables in "tempEnv"
eapply(tempEnv, fun)


##### Solution 2 using lapply() (Recommended) #####
# Define all variables in a list
myList <- list(a = 680, 
               b = 820, 
               c = 1040)

# apply fun() to all values in myList
lapply(myList, fun)
```

Answer (score 1):

You get an error because ls() only returns the names of the variables you've defined. ("a", "b" and "c")

Having said that, this example could be more easily be done using regular vector and scalar multiplication.

```
x = c(680, 820, 1040)
x * .8
```

If for some reason you want you use a list and function anyway I would recommend using lapply, like so:

```
a = 680
b = 820
c = 1040

list = list(a, b, c)

fun = function(x){ x*.8 }

lapply(list, fun)
```